# how can I add popup menu in right-click new->MyNewMenu on eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins

I'm try to create a eclipse plugin... but how can I add a my new popup menu in the new context?

for example I right-click on the project and put my menu inside of New->MyNewMenu

to add a new item on menu File-New I'm using this

```xml
<extension
     point="org.eclipse.ui.menus">
  <menuContribution
        locationURI="menu:new?after=additions">
     <menu
           id="Test1.menus.sampleMenu"
```

but if I try popup:menu:new?after=additions on locationURI this not work...

when I use the Spy plugin of RCP eclipse to know the popup id is returned

```xml
menu:null?after=additions
```

how can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

To get something in the File > New menu you must use the `org.eclipse.ui.newWizards` extension point to define a New wizard. On its own this will just make the New wizard appear in the 'Other...' section.

To add to the list of new wizards shown in the main part of the New menu you must use the `org.eclipse.ui.perspectiveExtensions` extension point to define a `newWizardShortcut` for your new wizard.

An example of a new wizard and shortcut from the JDT JUnit plugin:

```xml
<extension
     point="org.eclipse.ui.newWizards">
  <category
        name="%WizardCategory.name"
        parentCategory="org.eclipse.jdt.ui.java"
        id="org.eclipse.jdt.junit">
  </category>
  <wizard
        name="%TestCaseWizard.name"
        icon="$nl$/icons/full/etool16/new_testcase.gif"
        category="org.eclipse.jdt.ui.java/org.eclipse.jdt.junit"
        id="org.eclipse.jdt.junit.wizards.NewTestCaseCreationWizard">
     <class
           class="org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.wizards.NewTestCaseCreationWizard">
     </class>
     <description>
        %TestWizard.description
     </description>
  </wizard>
</extension>

<extension
     point="org.eclipse.ui.perspectiveExtensions">
  <perspectiveExtension
        targetID="org.eclipse.jdt.ui.JavaPerspective">
     <newWizardShortcut
           id="org.eclipse.jdt.junit.wizards.NewTestCaseCreationWizard">
     </newWizardShortcut>
  </perspectiveExtension>
</extension>
```

Comment: Congratulations Greg, is exactly what I needed.
But one question... the eclipse framework has any default screens to be used?
for example, I want to create a wizard that have a button to choose one project from the workspace, exists something like this to use in the framework?

I'm just beginning with the creation of eclipse plugins and I'm learning with the vogella articles

www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipsePlugIn/article.html
you recommend another one?

Comment: There are various selection dialogs available but not one for just projects, but it is not to hard to code, ask a new question if you are stuck. All of the Vogella tutorials are good and cover many aspects of Eclipse.