# How to get my own menu in File -> New in eclipse plugin?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

My question is almost same as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28236774/how-can-i-add-popup-menu-in-right-click-new-mynewmenu-on-eclipse).
The only difference is that I want the custom menu on top, like File -> New -> CustomMenu. CustomMenu should be the first in the New option.
I saw the answer to the linked question. It says

> To add to the list of new wizards shown in the main part of the New menu you must use the org.eclipse.ui.perspectiveExtensions extension point to define a newWizardShortcut for your new wizard.

Well, I tried this but I could only get my Wizard in "Other", not in the list visible directly.

Can anyone tell me how to get the custom menu on the top?

The relative part of my plugin.xml is as follows:

```
<extension
     point="org.eclipse.ui.newWizards">
  <wizard
        class="plugin.com.MyWizard"
        id="plugin.com.MyWizard"
        name="Inception">
  </wizard>
  <category
        id="plugin.com.myCategory"
        name="myCategory"
        parentCategory="org.eclipse.pde.PDE">
  </category>
</extension>
<extension
     point="org.eclipse.ui.perspectiveExtensions">
  <perspectiveExtension
        targetID="org.eclipse.pde.ui.PDEPerspective">
     <newWizardShortcut
           id="plugin.com.MyWizard">
     </newWizardShortcut>
  </perspectiveExtension>
</extension>
```

"plugin.com" is my plugin project name here. I may not be following the naming conventions but that is not the concern here.

Also, is category needed?

Comment: Well which perspective do you currently have open? You have defined a shortcut for the Plug-in Development perspective - it will only work when that perspective is active.

Comment: Oh okay. I have Java Perspective open. So now I changed the targetId to "org.eclipse.jdt.ui.JavaPerspective". But still I am not able to see my menu. Although, when targetId was set to PDEPerspective, I could see my menu when I changed my perspective to Plug-in Development, but even there it was near the end, not at the top where I want it.

Comment: @greg-449 Other entries in the code have no problem, right?

Comment: You aren't using the category so it is not really needed. The very top of the New menu is always just new projects. The second section is other new wizards but I don't think there is any way to control the order. You may have to Reset or Customize a perspective to get it to see new things.